# Configure MySQL db for a Spring-MVC project

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, hsqldb

My current Database properties are as follows:

[image]

I want my Database to be `MySQL`. Can someone please guide me how to change the properties so it gets saved in `MySQL`.

I have installed `MySQL` on my `Mac OSX`. The Username is `Root12` and password is `xxx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you just need to replace all the properties appropriately:

- the driverClassName is usually `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
- the url should be like `jdbc:mysql://host:3306/databaseName`
- the username and password you already have
- dialect depends on ORM you are using, for ex for hibernate [here](http://www.javabeat.net/list-of-hibernate-sql-dialects/) is the list

This is the basic configuration

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```