# mySQL on spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, web, model-view-controller

[image]I am learning spring mvc in book :Spring MVC: Beginner's Guide - Second Edition by Amuthan Ganeshan. in this book chapter 2 using   HyperSQL Database  and create database file create-table.sql and  insert-data.sql 
I have two question
1. how can I replay HyperSQL Database by mySQL Database 
2. how to execute sql file in maven project
Thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure MySQL db for a Spring-MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857275/configure-mysql-db-for-a-spring-mvc-project)

Comment: Maven will take care of project dependencies. The correct question would be how to execute sql in java or in java using spring.

Comment: I have take picture in my question, so i want  two sql file in picture are mysql (mysql file inside project) and add   SQL script to them